# UINavigationBar title font changes

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, uinavigationbar

I am using two fonts in my navigation bar title. One is Eurostile and another one is Museo Sans. For my home screen I am using Eurostile and rest of the screens I am using Museo Sans font. I am using the below code for setting the home screen title font.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
  UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
  UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Eurostile" size:25.0f]
 }];
```

The problem I am facing is, when I load the application, in the Home Screen it is showing the Eurostile font correctly. After opening the modal view controller and when I close it, immediately the home screen font changes to Museo Sans font... It is not showing up the Eurostile font correctly in the home screen.

```
ImagesGallery *galleryViewControler = [[ImagesGallery alloc] init];
galleryViewControler.LoginID= LoginID;
galleryViewControler.LoginUsername= LoginUserName;
galleryViewControler.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:galleryViewControler animated:YES];
```

I want Eurostile font in Home Screen even after navigating to other views. Can anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: If think you have font probelm, please check your font name in your project

Comment: If font name is wrong means in the first place home title will be with wrong font

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are calling the following code in your modal view controller.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
  UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
  UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo Sans" size:25.0f]
 }];
```

This code will set **ALL** UINavigationBars' appearance in your app.

On the other hand, navigation bar is shared by view controllers when you push, therefore simply changing the navigation bar's title font is not enough. Pushed view controller may also change the title font, when return to your Home Screen the font will be changed in that case.

As a solution, you can change the navigationbar's title font in viewDidAppear and change it back to whatever is default in your app in viewDidDisappear.

Comment: Except home screen, I am using Museo Sans font in all other Views. I am also using navigationController to move to other views. At that time there is no change in the font. Only when I use Modal View, at that time only font is changing in the home screen. This looks very strange.

Comment: Can you explain how you set the font globally for other views to use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

// HomeScreenViewController

```
-(void)viewWillAppear() {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
    UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
    UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Eurostile" size:25.0f]
                                                          }];
}
```

// AnotherViewController

```
-(void)viewWillAppear() {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
    UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
    UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo Sans" size:25.0f]
                                                          }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have test your `intention`, I distrust that your `project framework` did not set rationaly.

In my `test` I will show you my meaning:

[image: step01]
[image: set <code>nav1</code>'s font]
[image: set <code>nav2</code>'s font]
[image: nav1's controller <code>present</code> and <code>dismiss</code>]